# Win 10: Can't auto position administrator privileged windows stacked or side by side

Tags: windows-10

I want to re-position my windows on screen via `right-click on taskbar -> show windows stacked` but this does not work with windows that are open with administrator privileges.

Is there are way to stack admin. windows as well? I always have cmd.exe or powershell.exe open with admin. privileges alongside other windows and I am tired of manually resizing them.

Comment: That's weird, works fine for me.

Comment: Hmm, I just tried it again on my main desktop and a new virtual desktop and only the non administrator priviledge terminals/powershells were being stacked even when all 4 of them were open and scattered.

I'll investigate further and update this question/thread if I find any new information (hopefully it's not just me).